# How can I troubleshoot a service not starting at boot?

Tags: centos, boot, service, start

I've got a service set up to start at boot but it's not doing so and I don't know where to look (e.g. logs) to troubleshoot it.

I've verified the run level:

```
$ grep default /etc/inittab 
id:3:initdefault:
```

And the symlinks are there:

```
$ find /etc -name *beans*
/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K47beanstalkd
/etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K47beanstalkd
/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K47beanstalkd
/etc/rc.d/rc2.d/K47beanstalkd
/etc/rc.d/rc4.d/K47beanstalkd
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/K47beanstalkd
/etc/rc.d/rc5.d/K47beanstalkd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/beanstalkd
```

And when I start it manually (via "sudo /etc/init.d/beanstalkd start") it works fine.

Where do I start troubleshooting this?  Where might the boot sequence be logged that I can grep for issues?  This is a CentOS box if that matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your symlinks are there, but they're not what you want.  If you notice, yours are all prefixed with 'K' for kill.  They should be 'S' for start.

Fix this with `chkconfig beanstalkd on` and verify it with `chkconfig --list | grep beanstalkd`.

Comment: Yep, but the S *and* K files should be there, as it needs to start on entry to the runlevel, and stop on exit.

On another note: it DOES matter at little that it's CentOS/Fedora/RHEL, as Debian-like distros use update-rc.d instead of chkconfig.

Comment: Pedants unite! <g>  You are correct -- services that are to run should have both 'S' and 'K' scripts, not just 'S'.  Good catch.